# Horizontal lines with Samsung series 9/Intel Ivy Bridge

Tags: drivers, graphics, samsung, i915, ivybridge

I have a new Samsung 9 series laptop with Intel Ivy Bridge graphics and a dual Windows 8/Ubuntu 13.04 boot configuration. As soon I reach the login screen my graphics goes awry:

1) Black horizontal lines appear after a few seconds. They seem to be associated with bits of graphics rendered on the screen, and move around with them. They can leave a trace on the screen which persists for several minutes after a reboot.

2) At the top of the screen there are some lines a few pixels thick which flicker.

**Edit: this is a known problem. See links in comments below.**

However, if I start the system with nomodeset or noacpi, these problems do not occur. But this limits the operation of the laptop and the screen backlight no longer works.

I have installed intel-linux-graphics-installer and upgraded to the latest Intel drivers.

Comment: Found a bug report describing my symptoms precisely:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64332

Comment: Also here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/84. It seems this is a known problem (but with no known explanation). It can be "fixed" by using the nomodeset boot option, although that limits the operation of the machine, and usually disables the screen backlight. 

The only known "solution" is upgrading to 3.10 rc5 kernel, although no-one seems to know what change fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, it seems this is a known problem with some Samsung machines, that manifests on multiple Linux distros. No explanation has been forthcoming.

It can be worked around with the nomodeset or noacpi boot options, although that limits the operation of the machine, and usually disables the screen backlight.

The only known "solution" is upgrading to 3.10 rc5 kernel, although no-one seems to know what change fixes it. This fix worked for me, and according the bug reports below, for most other users.

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64332

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/84